# Realtime drawing using threads on android

Tags: android, multithreading, dictionary, android-asynctask, gps

I simply have a button in my application where onClick, I need it to start collecting gps points and do some process with it and on click again, i need it to stop that process.
Collected points will be pushed into an sqlite database while the thread is running and also I will draw lines on my map while the button is activated using collected gps points.

My problem is how to implement that thread and which way would be safest.
Extending `AsyncTask` class seems to be a robust solution but it runs only once and I need this thread to be available just like a toggle button for numerous times.
I tried the following test to see if I can maintain a simple thread in my app but it doesnt work. I cant use `stop()` method.
After I started my thread however and stopping by falsifying the controller in while loop, `start()` method to start it again just crashes.

```
class RunBuffer implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(toggleBufferIsActive){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                test++;
                Log.v("Thread running", String.valueOf(test));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and my toggle button is implemented as follows:

```
public void ToggleBuffer(View view) {

    if(this.toggleBufferIsActive){
        this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this.locationListener);
        this.gpsLatLongCollectionSize = 0;
        // TODO stop collecting and drawing buffer polygon thread
        this.toggleBufferIsActive = false;
    }
    else{
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, locationListener);
        // TODO start collecting and drawing buffer polygon thread
        this.toggleBufferIsActive = true;
        runBuffer.start();   // crashes here
    }
}
```

my runBuffer object is of type RunBuffer and instantiated in my onCreate() method in my activity.

any suggestion would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

> my runBuffer object is of type RunBuffer and instantiated in my
>   onCreate() method in my activity.

it is not possible. runBuffer can not be an instance of `RunBuffer`, since it extends Runnable. So you are probably wrapping this in a Thread. Something like:

```
 Thread runBuffer = new Thread(new RunBuffer());
 runBuffer.start();
```

Let's hypothesize the after you set

```
   this.toggleBufferIsActive = false;
```

the while loop ends correctly. In this case, you are trying to `restart`, which can not be done. An extract of the `Thread.start()` method from the doc:

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes the line you have written is correct. But my problem still stands. I thought of running my thread loop infinitely and putting my code into a block like if(toggleBufferIsActive){//my doe} but im not sure how stable that would be. since in that if block i will send data to sqlite database plus draw polygons on my map every 2-3 seconds